# Push associative array from for-loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

The for loop is supposed to loop 10 times.
When I just print the `$fname`, `$lname` and `$email`
I am getting the 10 data (Working fine)

But I need to store those value in an  associative array.

```
$assocDataArray = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['emails'] as $lead) {
        $fname = $lead['first_name'];
        $lname = $lead['last_name'];
        $email = $lead['value'];

        //put objects in array
        $assocDataArray += [ "First Name" => $fname ];
        $assocDataArray += [ "Last Name" => $lname ];
        $assocDataArray += [ "Email" => $email ];
    }
}

var_dump($assocDataArray);
```

`var_dump` is only giving me one array [Expected 10]

Comment: `$assocDataArray[] = [ "First Name" => $fname ,  "Last Name" => $lname , "Email" => $email ];` ?

Comment: This `$assocDataArray +=` should give you a syntax error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***This assignment:-***

```
$assocDataArray += [ "First Name" => $fname ];
$assocDataArray += [ "Last Name" => $lname ];
$assocDataArray += [ "Email" => $email ];
```

***Is wrong.Change it like below***

```
$assocDataArray[] = [ "First Name" => $fname ,"Last Name" => $lname ,"Email" => $email ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the key

```
$assocDataArray = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['emails'] as $lead) {
        $fname = $lead['first_name'];
        $lname = $lead['last_name'];
        $email = $lead['value'];

        //put objects in array
        $assocDataArray[ $key ]['First Name'] = $fname;
        $assocDataArray[ $key ]['Last Name'] = $lname;
        $assocDataArray[ $key ]['Email'] = $email;
    }
}

var_dump($assocDataArray);
```

```